# How to restore local database in ASP.Net web application using entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, restore, mdf, local-database

I want to add an option in my web application to restore database. this is `StoredProcedure`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Restore] @path NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN

        EXEC('ALTER DATABASE Kimiakesht SET OFFLINE')
        EXEC('ALTER DATABASE Kimiakesht SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE')

        RESTORE DATABASE Kimiakesht
FROM DISK = @path
WITH REPLACE

        EXEC('ALTER DATABASE Kimiakesht SET MULTI_USER')
        EXEC('ALTER DATABASE Kimiakesht SET ONLINE')
    END
```

And i call this procedure in application as you seen below:

```
string backupPath = "F:\restore\file.bak";

entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "EXEC [Restore] @path = N'" + backupPath + "'");
```

But i always get this error:

[image]

Comment: What is not clear about "User does not have permission"?

Comment: It's clear, but how can i solve that?

Comment: Well, who logs in to the database? That user should have appropriate permissions.

Comment: I'm using entity framework with this connection string: `<add name="Kimiakesht" connectionString="metadata=res://*/KimiakeshtModel.csdl|res://*/KimiakeshtModel.ssdl|res://*/KimiakeshtModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Kimiakesht.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`